# String formatted date picker date is off

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker that only has month, day, and year.  I am trying to output this selected date to a TextField using this code:

```
-(IBAction) dateChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"M/d/YYYY"];
    expirationDateField.text = [df stringFromDate:date];
    [df release];
}
```

For most dates, this works, but for some reason, when I pick January 1, 2009, or January 2, 2009, I end up getting "1/1/2008" or "1/2/2008" (this isnt specific to 2009).  I thought it was a time zone problem, but it wouldn't display the wrong year for January 2 if that were the case.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use lowercase `yyyy` for the year.

Uppercase `YYYY` returns the year of the start of the week that date falls in.
See [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Thanks, thought I looked over those before, must have missed or misunderstood the "Year of week" bit