# Xcode setDateFormat: wrong year

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, date-format, ekevent

I found this problem by using EKEvent to add an event to calendar with my App.

Since I didn't found any resources, I would like to know if you have ever hear about that.

I had an old app (developed IOS 5) that used successfully EKEvent with this date format

**@"yyyy/MM/dd:HH:mm"**

Now I have to realize a new app and I've tried to use the old code, but I found that by using that date format my app registered the event in 2014! The day was correct but, obviously, not the Year.

I fixed it by change the date format into

**@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"**

Do you know why?? Have you ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423179/nsdateformatter-show-wrong-year

Comment: If the format string was that far off from the actual format then it's hard to guess what might have been "read".  (Though keep in mind that Apple does some strange things based on locale setting and the 12/24 setting in the phone -- these can make a perfectly valid formatting string go down in flames.)

Comment: Unfortunatley ist not clar if its a duplicate, because the OP states that he used nad uses the correct small letter "y"

Comment: @AlexWien Yes, using YYYY will (currently) return 2014 so likely, but I chose not to vote for close until I was sure.

Comment: It's in the Xcode-Documentation, lookup phrase "Use Format Strings to Specify Custom Formats", second blueish box

Comment: Sorry, you are right!! With y instead of Y it works! I didn't find the duplicate answer you posted me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This bug usually occurs, when You use the Week of Year symbol "Y" big Y, while small "y" is correct. Are you sure that you use small "y" in the code?

small "y" is correct, please check again.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya -- Bzzzt!!  Wrong answer!

Comment: @HotLicks : i referred Joachim's link and I believed that this answer to be correct. :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya   small y is correct not big Y, as can be read in the link

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - I fail to see how using Y is going to fix anything.  Y is a specialized notation that is hardly ever valid.

Comment: Initially i commented here as **incorrect** and then i saw Joachim's comment, then I deleted my comment. As i dont have mac to test these codes now....