# ObjC Date always returns December 25 2017

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Needs some help with the following code:

```
self.dateTimestamp = userInfo[@"timestamp"];<- Returns UTC Time April 09 2018 11:09
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd YYYY HH:mm"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.dateTimestamp];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", dte); <-Date: Sun Dec 24 11:09:00 2017
```

Why do I have a date disparity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter show wrong year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423179/nsdateformatter-show-wrong-year)

Comment: Time Zone should be UTC, I also think you should set locale en_US_POSIX if you always get month in english.

Comment: I suggest you to use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY" to retrieve years. See the difference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133617/5154891

Comment: @ThomasMary i will give that try, i did't think that would make a different, but this might be one of those moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `YYYY` by `yyyy`:

```
NSString *dateTimestamp = @"April 09 2018 13:07";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];

NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateTimestamp];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", dte);
```

Result : `Mon Apr  9 13:07:00 2018`

But When using

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd YYYY HH:mm"];
```

It's logging : `Sun Dec 24 13:07:00 2017`

Comment: thaks, that was it, the lowercase y